# Maplex Label Expression in Python Parser of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, maplex

I am using a python code in ArcGIS to define the size of the labels of a point feature class. Therefore I am using a label expression (Maplex). The label size of the TEXTSTRING (string) should be defined by the TEXT_SIZE (double, with values like "3,5"). Generally the code is working, but not with special german characters (ü,ä,ö).

The code looks like that:

```
  def FindLabel ( [TEXTSTRING], [TEXT_SIZE] ):
      size = str([TEXT_SIZE])
      size_rec = str(float(size.replace(",","."))*4)
      size = size_rec.replace(".",",")
      return "<FNT size = '{0}'>{1}</FNT>".format(size, [TEXTSTRING])
```

Labels with these special characters are not displayed, labels with "normal" characters are displayed and sized correctly. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try something like this : "<FNT size = '"+size+">"+[TEXTSTRING]+"</FNT>"

Comment: the special characters then are displayed on the screen, but the size is not adapted correctly and i get the label: "<FNT size = '14,0>NAMEOFSTRING</FNT> instead of just the string...

Answer (score 1):

From comment

Try something like this :

```
"'<FNT size = '"+size+">"+[TEXTSTRING]+"</FNT>"
```